# Laravel create Query SQL

Tags: laravel

I need help to create my query.
I created the following query in SQL

```
SELECT id_funcionario, MAX(created_at) from irs GROUP by id_funcionario
```

I try to switch to Larevel but I'm wrong and I can't put the groupby

```
    $irs = irs::join('utilizadors','utilizadors.id','=', 'irs.id_funcionario')
    ->MAX('created_at')
   
    ->get([ 'utilizadors.id', 'utilizadors.nome', 'irs.id', 'irs.id_funcionario','irs.created_at', 'irs.dependentes', 'irs.titulares_rendimento', 'irs.situacoes_especiais']);
    return view('irs-total', ['itens' => $irs]);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `::join()` when your original SQL doesn't have any kind of `JOIN ...` clause? I would expect the correct syntax would be something like `irs::select(['id_funcionario', DB::raw('MAX(created_at)'])->groupBy('id_funcionario')->get()`. If you need to verify, replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` to see the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

```
 $irs = DB::table('irs')
             ->join('utilizadors','utilizadors.id','=', 'irs.id_funcionario')
             ->select(DB::raw('irs.created_at'), 'utilizadors.id', 
                'utilizadors.nome', 'irs.id', 'irs.id_funcionario','irs.created_at', 
                'irs.dependentes', 'irs.titulares_rendimento', 
                'irs.situacoes_especiais')
             // add your groupBy data
             ->groupBy('')
             ->get();
```

Comment: Why `DB::table('irs')`? They have a model `irs`.

Comment: I think it's the first `table` he's trying to join with `utilizadors`

Comment: You're missing the point of that comment; if they have a Model `irs`, you should encourage using it instead of `DB::table('irs')`, so `irs::join(...)->select(...)` and so on.